# How to hide add to cart (ajax) off grid/product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, login, ajax

Looking for a fix on requiring login for 1.9 with porto theme. I've checked the standard feature listed on many places on how to hide via login but it seems like my `lists.phtml` format is different since ajax is built in the coding?

Example of the coding on my file,

```
<?php if($product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php  if ( !($product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasOptions($product)/*$_product->getData('has_options')*/ || $product->isGrouped()) ) :  ?>
        <a href="<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code) && !Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?><?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php else: ?>javascript:void(0)<?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>onclick="setLocationAjax(this,'<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')"<?php elseif(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/category/qty_field", $code)): ?>onclick="document.getElementById('addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>').submit()"<?php endif; ?>><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <a href="<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>javascript:showOptions('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')<?php else: ?><?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?><?php endif; ?>" class="addtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>"><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></a>
        <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'>Options</a>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart outofstock" title="<?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></a>
```

Adding the default `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` with additional lines just fails to load my page.

Any advice?

Comment: try if($product->isSaleable()&&Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())

Comment: So add this in the first line of my code as posted above? Or make a new php tag? Once I did add that into the first line it did hide add to cart although only 1 item was displayed per page vs my default 36.